# PHP 7.4 typeError on database operations

Tags: php, pdo, php-7

I would like to encode some data from a database to JSON.

This class opens a connection to my database.

```
<?php

namespace Database;

use PDO;
use PDOException;

class Connection
{
    private string $server = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wbs";
    private string $user = "root";
    private string $pass = "";
    private array $options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,);
    protected PDO $con;

    public function openConnection()
    {
        try {
            $this->con = new PDO($this->server, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->options);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Something went wrong with the database connection: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $this->con;
    }

    public function closeConnection()
    {
        unset($this->con);
    }
}
```

This class queries the database for any items

```
<?php

namespace Task;

use PDO;
use PDOStatement;
use Database\Connection;

class Task
{
    private Connection $conn;
    private PDO $pdo;
    private PDOStatement $PDOStatement;


    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->conn = new Connection();
    }
    public function SqlQuery(): PDOStatement
    {
       $this->pdo = $this->conn->openConnection();

       $this->PDOStatement = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tasks` 
       LEFT JOIN `projects` ON 'projects.projectid' = 'tasks.projectid' 
       LEFT JOIN `moscow` ON 'moscow.moscowid' = 'tasks.moscowid'");

       $this->PDOStatement->execute();

       return $this->PDOStatement;
    }
}

<?php

namespace Read;

use PDO;
use PDOStatement;
use Task\Task;


require_once("../config/Connection.php");
require_once("../object/Task.php");

class Read
{
    private PDOStatement $PDOStatement;
    private Task $task;
    private int $items;
    private array $task_array;
    private array $task_item;
    private array $row_count;
    private array $row_items;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->task = new Task();
    }

    public function EncodeToJson(): string
    {
        $this->PDOStatement = $this->task->SqlQuery();
        $this->items = $this->PDOStatement->rowCount();

        if ($this->items > 0) {

            $this->task_array = array();
            $this->task_array["records"] = array();

            while ( $this->row_count = $this->PDOStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $this->row_items = $this->row_count;
                extract($this->row_items);

                $this->task_item = array(
                    "id" => $id,
                    "task_name" => $task_name,
                    "task_owner" => $task_owner,
                    "developer" => $developer,
                );

                array_push($this->task_array["records"], $this->task_item);
            }

            http_response_code(200);

            return json_encode($this->task_array);
        }
    }
}

$Read = new Read();

echo $Read->EncodeToJson();
```

This class loops through all the fetched data, stores it in an array and encodes it to JSON. 
The error occurs on line 41 which is the `while` loop. the error returns this

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Typed property Read\Read::$row_count
>   must be array, bool used in C:\laragon\www\WBS\php\api\task\Read.php
>   on line 41.

Checking the docs on the `fetch` method

> The return value of this function on success depends on the fetch
>   type. In all cases, FALSE is returned on failure.

It would make sense on why the typeError happens, I am just confused as to what i should make my field `row_count` I tried casting it to an array with no success and one would assume the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` would return an array instead of a boolean.

I am just very confused on how PHP uses these typed properties and how to properly use them with database operations.

Comment: there isn't any class that loops over database result

Comment: you need to check the value returned by ->fetch() before you assign it to row_count. Then you can make sure it's not false first. Either that, or don't strongly-type your $row_count variable.

Comment: Not strong typing the $row_count variable fixes the issue, but is their no way to implement typed properties for result sets?

Comment: What you are doing there is rather bogus anyway, if you ask me. `while ( $this->row_count = $this->PDOStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` – why is the fetched _record_ assigned to a property called `row_count` here to begin with? Makes rather little sense, especially considering how you are doing `$this->row_items = $this->row_count;` inside the loop next. […]

Comment: […] Why is there a class property used in this place to begin with? If this is only a “helper variable” to be used to loop over the result set and process the data inside the loop, and won’t be needed afterwards any more anyway - then this should be exactly that, a local _variable_, and not a class property.

Comment: Yea i figured that out myself and fixed the issues, thank you for the insight anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use the properties in your method. You should use local variables, but even they are not needed. Please avoid `extract()` at all cost. It is extremely messy solution.

You have turned what should be a single line of code into a full method with a lot of unnecessary stuff. It is enough to just do this:

```
public function EncodeToJson(): string
{
    return json_encode(['records' => $this->task->SqlQuery()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)]);
}
```

However, the whole class becomes pointless. You are not using it in OOP way. The class you have created is just noise in your code. You can remove the `Read` class and simply call the method on `Task` directly.

```
echo json_encode(['records' => (new Task())->SqlQuery()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)]);
```

Your `Task` class also has problems. You should follow the dependency injection design and pass the connection as a parameter to `__construct`.

```
<?php

namespace Task;

use PDO;
use PDOStatement;

class Task {
    private PDO $pdo;

    public function __construct(PDO $conn) {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }

    public function read(): PDOStatement {
        $PDOStatement = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tasks` 
            LEFT JOIN `projects` ON 'projects.projectid' = 'tasks.projectid' 
            LEFT JOIN `moscow` ON 'moscow.moscowid' = 'tasks.moscowid'");

        $PDOStatement->execute();

        return $PDOStatement;
    }
}
```

and then when you create an object, pass the connection in.

```
$pdo = $connection->openConnection();
$task = new Task($pdo);
```

On an unrelated note: **Never display error messages!**. Don't catch the exceptions if the only thing you want to do is echo the error. Leave the exceptions alone. If you want to implement error handler, it should be logging to a file.